# How to save multiple files in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, file, mongoose

i am getting files  from api response. these files i have to save in mongoDB  database. 
code is here and i am getting unzip files but i don't have any idea to save files in database

```
function drugbank_download_zip(filename) {
    options = {
        "auth": `${DRUGBANK_USERNAME}:${DRUGBANK_PASSWORD}`
    };
    return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => https.get(DOWNLOAD_URL, options, (res) => {
        const { statusCode } = res;

        let error;
        if (statusCode !== 200) {
            // Consume response data to free up memory
            res.resume();

            reject(new Error(`Request Failed.\nStatus Code: ${statusCode}`));
            return;
        }

        let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
        res.on('data', (d) => writeStream.write(d));

        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log("finished downloading!")
            writeStream.close();
            fulfill(filename);
        });
   }));
}

async function each_drug_file(zip_path, callback) {
    const zip = fs.createReadStream(zip_path)
          .pipe(unzip.Parse({forceStream: true}));

    for await (const entry of zip) {
        let filename = entry.path
        if (filename.endsWith(".json")) {
            entry.buffer().then((buffer) => {
                callback(JSON.parse(buffer.toString("utf8")));
            });
        } else {
            // free memory from this file
            entry.autodrain();
        }
    }
}


drugbank_download_zip('drugs.zip').
    then((result) => {
        each_drug_file("drugs.zip", (drug_data) => {
            // TODO: do something awesome here!
            console.log(`${drug_data.drugbank_id}, ${drug_data.name}`);
        });
    },
    (err) => console.log(`failed to download with error ${err}`));
```

please help if you can thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can look into GridFS. As architecture level, you should not save such file in Mongo DB. It is waste, because you cant perform any operation. If you still want to save. You can look a solution to store as Binary.

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.

**For more detail:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/